# Can there be different representation of the same public PGP key?

Tags: public-key, pgp, file-format

I have **two PGP public key files**:

**File1 was created with Kleopatra / Gpg4win**.

**File2** was created by the following procedure:

1. Import File1 as public key for EmailAccount1 into **Thunderbird 78.4.0**
2. Send this imported public key via email from Thunderbird 78.4.0 from EmailAccount1 to EmailAccount2
3. Save the public key file that was attached to this email received at EmailAccount2

File1 and File2 seem to have the same fingerprint.
Just like File1, File2 can be used to encrypt messages, which both can successfully be decrypted with the private key that had been created with Kleopatra when creating public key File1. So, both File1 and File2 seem to work as *the same* public key in combination with the private key.

But interestingly, **File2**

- is 14 bytes **smaller in size than File1**
- has a longer line length than File1
- has less lines than File1
- differs from File1 in the first 3 bytes after the "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" line
- differs in the last 5 bytes, just before the "-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" line

**Is it normal and permissible to have differing versions of one and the same public key?** Or should the public key string never get changed, no matter what?

Comment: Different line length (and other characteristics you've mentioned) reflects difference in various PEM-like base64 textualization. When you decode your key files from base64 to binary, they'll be identical. It's perfectly normal as long as they don't cause interoperability problems.

Comment: The last _line_ before the PGP-armor 'END' line, which happens to be 5 characters representing 3 bytes, is a CRC of the data, and should not differ if the data is the same. The data could be different but still contain the same key because of v3 versus v4 packet format, or because of different choices on what signature(s) to include, but the latter would almost certainly be more than 14 bytes difference. Note that the fingerprint displayed by PGP programs like gpg/kleo and tbird is the fingerprint of the _key_ not of a file that might or might not contain the key.